# AngularJs changing $location.path does not work

Tags: angularjs

I realise that this problem has been presented before.
But none of the answers appear to solve this problem.

I have a moderate knowledge of Angular and have produced quite a lot of angular code, I'm not a complete beginner.

I have started working on a MEAN app, so all the client side is Angular. And after two days of banging my head on the wall, I can't get a perfectly simple location.path(newPath) to work in a function in the $scope of a controller.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('core').controller('HeaderController', 
        [   '$scope', 
            '$location',
function($scope, $location) {


    //THIS LINE OF CODE, ON ARRIVAL IN THE CONTROLLER, WORKS
    //- it changes the path no problem.
    //$location.path('/it/vino/chianti/ChiantiClassico');   


    //But trying to set $location.path() DOES NOT WORK IN THE
    //FOLLOWING FUNCTION.
    //This function is called correctly from an ng-click event on a link. 
    //Therefore there should be no need to call apply(). 
    //However I have also tried both $apply and $timeout.

    $scope.changeLanguage = function(lang){

        //Right, let's try setting the path..
        $location.path('/it/vino/chianti/ChiantiClassico');

        //now we log $location.path() in the console and it 
        //gives the correct answer, which is:
        //'/it/vino/chianti/ChiantiClassico',
        //(but the path does not actually change in the browser address bar).
        console.log('$location.path():', $location.path()); //correct!

        //But if I also log the location object and I look inside, 
        //the path hasn't changed there !
        console.log('$location:', $location); //The path is the old one!

        //And the address bar has not changed
    };


}//end function
```

]);

I have debugged and scoured the objects looking for another $location object or some other mistake. - But there is only one $location object - found in the 'closure' section of the stack.

I can't see any kind of callback mistake here, I'm not trying to use an object that hasn't yet been defined or something like that.

Here is the calling link code from the view for completeness, nothing strange here, I've tried calling from buttons as well, the function is called correctly:

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-ng-click="changeLanguage('it')">italiano</a>
```

Comment: Have you try to remove the href="javascript:;" ?

Comment: I changed it to a button, same result

Comment: Are you doing some async stuff with $timeout ?

Comment: No, I put it there just to try $timeout. There is no code there that now uses it. I'll edit and remove it.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm having a similar issue. Except any redirect takes me back to my root path! :/

Comment: @AR. No, I didn't solve this exact problem. I eventually completely changed how I did internationalisation/languages. I installed ui-router and then searched for a definitive solution for i18, which at the moment doesn't really exist. There's a whole issue on GitHub open about it https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/185 and my solution is the penultimate comment. So no, I didn't solve this, sorry I can't help.

Comment: @AR. Actually, thinking about it, and looking at my last comment: the answer is that we shouldn't be fiddling about with the location when there is good, tested code about like ui-router that can solve these kinds of problems for us. I gave up worrying about the weird problem and redesigned the whole thing around other people's more reliable code!

Comment: You're absolutely right about doing things based on reliable, tested code, and I did as much searching around as time permitted. However, I'm just a hobbyist programmer with no time/resources to do a big re-factor. I've added an answer with what worked for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

I struggled for a while with the same issue. The problem was updating the URL with the ID of a newly created object (ID was generated by the DB and retrieved as part of the save process).

What worked well for me was simply:

`$window.location.assign(newURL);`

Comment: Well I can't quite give you the answer, but +1 as it's an interesting solution for people in a similar predicament

Answer (score 0):

May be your problem is that click on tag a make some navigation...

Not a 'true' answer, but some ways to explore:

- try to remove the javascript in href
- replace 'a' by 'button'
- ng-click="changeLanguage('it,$event)" and in changeLanguage function:
  event.preventDefault() (or some stopPropagation)

Hope it can help..

Comment: Thanks Thierry, but I'm sure that's not the problem. That code is ok. You can change the calling code to: <input type="button" value="English" data-ng-click="changeLanguage('en')"/>, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I meet same problem, finally, I use this code:
$window.location = '/#/path/to/xx' :